# Web Audio API in Safari - FFT will not detect frequencies above 19k accurately

Tags: javascript, safari, fft, web-audio-api, frequency-analysis

I am writing code to detect the frequency being played using the Web Audio API FFT, targeting high frequencies above 18kHz. It works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and Edge but in Safari it is very inaccurate and doesn't register frequencies at all over 19kHz. Is there a known issue for Safari struggling to detect the highest frequencies?

My code is as follows:

```
    async connectMicAudio() {
        try {
            let stream;
            const constraints = {
                echoCancellation: false,
                noiseSuppression: false,
                autoGainControl: false,
                mozAutoGainControl: false,
                mozNoiseSuppression: false,
            };
            if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
                stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    audio: true,
                });
            } else {
                navigator.getUserMedia = // account for different browsers
                    navigator.getUserMedia ||
                    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                    navigator.msGetUserMedia;

                stream = await navigator.getUserMedia({
                    audio: true,
                });
            }
            stream.getAudioTracks()[0].applyConstraints(constraints);
            this.audioStream = stream;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        }
        let stream = this.audioStream;
        const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        const audioContext = new AudioContext();
        if (!this.sampleRate) {
            this.sampleRate = audioContext.sampleRate;
        }
        const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
        analyser.fftSize = audioParams.FFT_SIZE;
        analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0;
        try {
            const microphone = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
            microphone.connect(analyser);
        } catch {
            alert('Please allow microphone access.');
        }
        const processor = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(
            audioParams.BUFFER_SIZE,
            1,
            1
        ); // single channel audio (mono)
        processor.connect(audioContext.destination);

        this.analyser = analyser;
        this.processor = processor;
    }
```

Then for the FFT I use:

```
this.processor.onaudioprocess = () => {
        let fftData = new Float32Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(fftData);
        let highPassed = highPass(fftData, this.sampleRate);
        let loudest = findLoudestFreqBin(highPassed, this.sampleRate);
        console.log('loudest: ', loudest);
};
```

This extracts the frequency data from each buffer, highPass just zeroes anything under 18k and findLoudestFreqBin just returns the centre point of the bin with the highest amplitude. When I play anything above 19k on Safari, the highest amplitude will always be in a lower bin in the 18-19k range.

As I said this code works perfectly with other browsers so I'm assuming it's an issue with Safari's implementation of the Web Audio API. If anyone has had a similar issue and knows a workaround that would be a huge help.

Comment: Are these other browsers running on the same hardware and/or OS ?

Comment: @PaulR yes, chrome firefox and safari all running on a new MacBook air. My colleague has used a MacBook pro and an iPhone and its the same issue, only safari fails while other browsers work fine.

Comment: Can you check that the default sample rate is the same in all cases ? (E.g. if Safari defaults to 44.1 kHz and the others default to 48 kHz then that might explain it.) Failing that, the next thing I would do is dump some time domain frames and plot them and see if there are any obvious differences.